# Bios startup error: 1 long beep and 2 short. But graphics is onboard

Tags: graphics-card, bios, hardware-failure

I have a desktop computer here that can't boot after a long power outage (it was behind a UPS/surge protector though).  It won't boot now and is giving 1 long beep and 2 short ones. The motherboard is an ASUS M2NBP-VM CSM, which uses an Award BIOS.  From searching online, places say that 1 long beep and two short ones mean that the graphics card isn't working. But this motherboard has onboard graphics, which is what I'm using. There are no other graphics cards in the system. Although I tried putting one in to see if that resolved the issue, which it didn't.

I also tried clearing the BIOS to see if some issue there needed to be reset. Nothing.  I checked the motherboard for obvious signs of being fried and can't find anything wrong. Any ideas as to how to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: An onboard GPU can still be broken. Sounds like yours is.

Comment: @deltaray: If it was on a UPS wouldn't that have allowed it to shut down cleanly?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your on board graphics chip died.

First clear your RTC RAM.

.
[image]

If clear RTC RAM does not get the on board video working, Install a graphics card into your **PCI Express x16 slot** and connect your monitor to it.
.
[image]

You should be able to get a post screen now, if you do enter the bios and set the PCIe slot as default video if it is not already set.

[image]

.

[Your motherboard manual can be found on this page](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM2/M2NBPVM_CSM/#download)

Comment: You may need to clear the CMOS because the CMOS may be set to only use the integrated graphics controller on boot.

Comment: It seems that neither of you read my full post.

Comment: You never said what type of video card (x1, x16, pci) you installed did you? Seems you did not include details in your question. We do the best we can given the details posted in the question. Check your bios settings after you install the card, be sure it is the preferred video device.